# Is it possible to overlay custom audio on top of a video?

Tags: android

I want to be able to overlay an audio track onto a video all within the Android API. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you need, but if you're looking for doing this during playback (not changing the actual video file) you can create two mediaplayers, and set the volume of the one that plays video to 0 using `setVolume` method.

Comment: It's not quite what I am looking for but may be a work around for playing on the device. If you do this do they start and stay in sync ok?

Comment: you want to overlay audio over video.. you mean after processing user could listen 2 audio at a time ?